# No input file specified Nginx WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fastcgi, php

blog.mydomain.com/phpinfo.php (which simply shows `phpinfo()`) works fine.

What am I missing?

Directory root of my blog is /usr/share/nginx/html/blog/

I'm using Centos.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf is as default.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf:

```
server {
    server_name  blog.fuzzybee7.com www.blog.fuzzybee7.com;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/global/php.conf;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/blog;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/global/php.conf:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/nginx/conf.d/global/php.conf try this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Faishal's answer should have been fine, but he did a small mistake, he used `$args` instead of `$uri` or `$request_uri`, so try doing this;

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri; 
}
```

This should pass the uri correctly to the index.php